# MySql Dump and TimeZone for DateTime Columns

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

We recently moved our mysql server from EST to GMT.  In doing this our DateTime columns currently all have the incorrect offsets.

For instance when the server was in EST and the client was in PST a local PST DateTime of 2012-01-01 00:00:0000 would be stored as ...03:00:0000 on the EST server.  Now after moving the server the offset should actually be 7 not 3.  As there is an extra 4 hours between PST and GMT.

I have read that Timestamp columns can be modified using the uct-tz dump switches but have not yet found a fix for DateTime Columns.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the reason you aren't simply running an `UPDATE` ?

Comment: We have a very large number of databases and tables that are being migrated to this new server.  We have no control of the timezone of the new server.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, please help me out: You can query the new server's timezone. You know the timezone of the old server. You can calculate the offset. What stops you from creating a simple SQL script, that updates the relevant columns? This could even come in handy on future relocs!

Comment: I agree this could be done.  I guess I was hoping for a "built-in" way of doing this via mysqldump or mysql import.  Seems this kinda thing would be more common...

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to this. Seems kinda retarded for mysql's table dump to output a string value sans time zone when the values are actually stored as unix timestamps. Why not dump the timestamp? Or at least have a timezone so the date can be known unambiguously.

Comment: In answer to the above suggestions, it's not as simple as subtracting the difference between two known time zones. If either time zone has Daylight Saving Time or "Summer Time", the offset changes. It would not be safe to simply add or subtract a number of hours from every datetime value in the database.